# How to update a value depending on a condition?

Tags: pine-script

I am using Pine Script which is used in tradingview.com.

My question is: Is it possible to update a variable depending on a condition?

Here is a variable called 'index' which increase everytime the 'buycondition' is False. The variable 'index' returns to 0 everytime  when the 'buycondition' becomes True.

```
index = 0
if (buycondition == 0) // 0 for False
    index += 1        
else:
    index = 0
```

The goal is to know the candlestick distance between the last 'buycondition' and the last 'sellcondition'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please read about [Variable declaration](https://www.tradingview.com/pine-script-docs/en/v4/language/Expressions_declarations_and_statements.html#id8) to gain an understanding how this works.
A Pine script is executed on every bar. See [Execution Model](https://www.tradingview.com/pine-script-docs/en/v4/language/Execution_model.html).

The way you wrote it, has your `index` re-initialized to 0 on every bar.

You should use it like this:

```
var int index = 0

if (buycondition == 0) // 0 for False
    index := index + 1        
else:
    index := 0
```

Comment: Thank you so much !

Answer (score 0):

Actually you intend to measure the time of the condition "buycondition == 0", right?

Then everything is fine!
Put this block into a function, you call e.g. every second, and index delivers that candlestick time in seconds.

E.g. (I'm new to Pine)

```
index := 0

getCD(buycondition) =>
    if (buycondition == 0) // 0 for False
        index := index + 1        
    else:
        index := 0
    index // return value
```